# Cocoa OpengGL: draw texture and round corners

Tags: cocoa, opengl, textures, rounded-corners, nsopenglview

If I use a standard `NSWindow` to host a `NSOpenGLView` which extends for all the window frame, the two bottom corners of the window are automatically rounded.

When swithcing to `NSBorderlessWindowMask` I have to handle corner rounding myself.
I have already implemented a transparent custom `NSWindow` and a rounded custom `NSView` and they both work fine.
After that I have implemented a transparent `NSOpenGLContext` by setting `NSOpenGLCPSurfaceOpacity` to 0.
If I set a color background for the OpenGL context, the view is drawn correctly and I obtain the desired rounded corner.

But, since the app is a movie player, I need to draw the texture corresponding to every movie frame.

When I do this (using `glTexCoord2f` and `glVertex2f`) the texture is drawn till corners and therefore the image is drawn till outside of the rounded corners and I loose the rounded aspect of my window.

What does the system do when the window is standard and **non** `NSBorderlessWindowMask` that I can't seem to be able to reproduce?

What is the best way to round the corner of the texture while drawing it to the frame buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the texture to a geometry with rounded corners, use an additional alpha mask on the movie texture with rounded corners, or use the stencil test to round off your viewport's corners.

Comment: Have you got a sample for one of these solutions? Because I'm very new to programming, expecially to OpenGL, and I don't actually know how to implement what you suggested

Comment: I have figured it out. I have used an additional alpha mask. Thank you very much for your help!